# Creating a web service that requires client certificates

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, ssl, iis-7

I am currently working on a project that has the following components (all .NET 2.0)

1. Client Application
2. Web Service Invocation API
3. Web Service

In summary the Client Application creates and instance of the API and this calls the Web Service.  Nice and simple and this all works exactly as I want it to.

The next stage of the project was to secure the Web Service with SSL.  So I have created a "Self Signed CA" and from this signed a server certificate for IIS.  Again, nice and simple and this all works exactly as I want it to.

The next stage of the project is to secure the Web Service by requiring the invoker to supply a client certificate.  So I have created a client certificate (via the Self Signed CA).  I am then adding this to the Web Service invocation call in the API:

```
WSBridge.Processor processor = new WSBridge.Processor();
processor.Url = this.endpoint;
processor.ClientCertificates.AddRange(this.clientCertificates);
processor.Timeout = (int)Settings.Default["DefaultTimeout"];
```

In debug I can see that `this.clientCertificates` contains the certificate I created.  So in theory it is being presented to the web server.

However, when I attempt to call the Web Service I get the following exception in the API:

```
The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
```

Fairly self explantory, but I have no idea what is causing the problem.

Other relevant information:

- In my dev environment Client, API & Web Service are all running on the same machine
- If I attempt to access the Web Service Description in IIS I get the following error (I am not prompted to choose a client certificate):

  *HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
  The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.*
- The client certificate is loaded into the Personal store for the current user, the CA root is in trusted root for the local machine and current user.
- If I switch off "Require SSL" and put "Client Certificates" on accept in IIS I can make my request.  However when I look at `HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.Count` in the Web Service this comes back as 0.
- I need to be able to run my development with client certificates as portions of the service code use the CN of the client certificate to perform various actions.  I could hack it in but it would be nice to be able to do a real end to end.
- All the certificates mention here were generated using OpenSSL.  I am developing on Windows 7 so I do not have the facility to install Microsoft CA

So, does anybody have any ideas as to the cause of this problem?

As an aside (not worth creating a new question for this) - for some reason when I enable SSL for the Web Service Visual Studio is no longer able to debug the service.

**EDIT : Some more information**

- The client certificate has an intended purpose of `<All>`
- Although I am working on localhost the server certificate for the web server was issued to `devserver.xyz.com` so I have changed my hosts file to point that to localhost.  As such I can now browse (with client certs switched off in IIS) to my service descriptor page without seeing any SSL certificate warnings.

Comment: Have you added the CA certificate to the trusted certificate store?

Comment: Yes, the CA cert is in Trusted Root Certification authorities.  Additionally if I browse to the Web Service (with client certs off) on HTTPs I can see that the certificate chain is intact and trusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I have **solved** the problem, in summary this was due to the format of the client certificate this should have been PKCS12.

**More Detail**

Although the MMC Certificate plugin was showing the client certificate in the personal store for the current userm I noticed that when viewing the same store via Internet Explorer (Tools -> Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates) the certificate was not present.

After a little Googling it seems that IE will only accepts PKCS12 format for client certificates, so I convert the certificate with the following OpenSSL command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client_alpha.cer -inkey client_alpha.key -out client_alpha.p12
```

I then imported the p12 file into IE which allowed me to browse to the Web Service description page with full client/server certificated TLS.

Once I had made this change, I then retried by client application and this now works aswell.  This is due to the fact that IIS, like IE, will only accept client certificates in PKCS12 format.